# Creating a tar file in a specified directory in a shell script

Tags: tar, arguments

I am trying to create a tar file of an existing file or directory (`file_dir_name`) in a specified directory (`dir_path`). I need the tar file to be named `new_name.tar` in the new directory. However, when I execute the below command, the tar file is saved in the directory I am currently in. Can anyone help me fix this?

```
tar -cvf "$new_name.tar" "$file_dir_name" -C "$dir_path"
```

Comment: Is `-C $dir_path` only there to try forcing the creation of the tarball in `dir_path`? If you are using GNU `tar`, it should be warning you that the `-C` option has no effect as the last argument. Are you trying to do the equivalent of `tar cvf "$name.tar" "$file_or_dir" && mv "$name.tar" "$dir_path/"` - where `file_or_dir` is an absolute path or a path relative to the current directory (not to `dir_path`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the path to where you want the new tarball stored, e. g. `tar cvf "${dir_path}"/new_name.tar "$file_dir_name" -C "$dir_path"`.

This presumes that the direcory corresponding with `file_dir_name` exists in `dir_path`.

Comment: will this work if the file does not exist in dir_path/ how would i make it work if it doesn't exist within the directory?

Comment: If it does not exist it will probably throw an error.  You can use `test -d "${dir_path}/${file_dir_name}"` to verify it exists as a pre-tarring sanity check.

Comment: Do you know how I would modify your original answer so that it can accept relative or absolute paths? right now it only works for absolute

Comment: Relative paths should work; the question is, relative to _what_?  In this context, the paths are relative to `$PWD` in environment from which the command is run.