# Checking if tar file exists | bash script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, tar

I am trying to test if the tar file I am about to create already exists. If it doesn't then I want to create the tar file (this part of the code works). However the if statement testing if that file name for the tar file exists, doesn't work (doesn't actually test if the tar file exists, just skips straight to the else statement even if the tar file does already exist). Any ideas?

Note: fire_dir_name is the name of the file we are trying to tar ie.) myfile1.txt

```
#create variable for new name of file/dir
date=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
new_name="$file_dir_name.$date"
file_name="$new_name.tar"
echo $file_name

#check if tar file exists already
if [ -f "$file_name" ]
then
        echo "$file_name" exists
else

        # create tar file 
        tar -cvf $dir_path/$new_name.tar $file_dir_name -C $dir_path
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you say "it doesn't work", can you be more specific? If possible, reproduce actual output from the script so we can see _how_ it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Thank! edited :)

Comment: There are a number of variables used that you never show the definition of. `file_dir_name` and `dir_path`, for example. If you use `"$dir_path/$new_name.tar"` in place of `"$file_name"` in the test, does it work?

Comment: You already asked the essence of this question as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/613024/186590), obviously you didn't understand how `tar` is supposed to operate. I propose you learn pax, it's easier, modern, and is expected to be more portable, and I'll provide an answer based on pax.

Comment: @DannyNiu Using another tool would not help if it's the pathnames in the various variables that are wrong.

Comment: @Kusalananda, very certainly. I'll try my best explain how to make better use of variables for him as well.

Comment: Thanks guys! variables are not wrong, the new_name indeed is the correct name as the file I am trying to tar. It just isn't searching if that file exists properly. ie.) if file1.txt.20200918.tar eactually does exist, it won't show that

Comment: Is `$file_dir_name` in the `$dir_path` directory? Or is it in the current directory (assuming the current working directory is not `$dir_path`)? I'm asking because you are creating `$new_name.tar` in `$dir_path` and testing for the existence of the `$file_name` file in the current working directory, without telling us if the two directories are supposed to be the same one.

Comment: file_dir_name is the name of the directory and dir_path is the name of the directory to store the tar file

Comment: A late bit of general advice: in cases such as this, the guidance on creating a _minimal, reproducible example_ [given on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies. To make the issue reproducible, this question should also mention your script's shebang line (and which shell it actually is in case it was `#!/bin/sh`), how you are invoking it (the full command line, including parameters), the path of the directory the script is invoked from, the values of `dir_path` and `file_dir_name`. Allowing other users to reproduce your issue is of invaluable help.

Comment: Problematic edit has been roll backed

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that you must test for the same filename you are creating

```
#check if tar file exists already
if [ -f "$file_name" ]
then
        ...
else
        # create tar file 
        tar -cvf "$file_name" ...
        ...
fi
```

Additionally, there is no reason `file_name` can't be a full path.

```
file_name="$dir_path/$new_name.tar"
```

It is probably less error prone to put the directory into the variable name.
It may be better style to call the variable `tar_name` or `tar_path` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks! but what is I want to create the tar file to a specific directory (ie. dir_path)?

Comment: @NatalieLloyd Is there anything that prevents you from running `if [ -f "$dir_path/$new_name.tar" ]; then ...; else tar -cvf "$dir_path/$new_name.tar" ...; fi`? This is the whole point of this Q/A: since you are not changing the working directory, you can, and probably should, simply use the same path expression when performing the `-f` test and when creating the tar archive.

Answer (score 0):

If we ignore the part where you missed the `fi` clause, the essence of the problem revolves around just before your invocation of `tar`.

Assume you want to

- create a tarball named `$newname`
- for the directory entry `$file_dir_name`
- inside `$dir_path`

You should first `cd` to `$dir_path`. I'm not sure if the `-C` flag is portable, but the newer `pax` command don't have it for the obvious reason of reducing complexity.

Using `-C` flag has another problem: if $dir_path is relative, it'd create the tarball in the wrong place.

The reason your file existence check fail is, I guess, you didn't change to the directory that `$file_name` is supposed to exist.

Next, specify the output destination as filename of the tarball, and the `$file_dir_name` as operands to the `tar/pax` command.

Improved command:

```bsh
...

#check if tar file exists already
cd "$dir_path"

if [ -f "$file_name" ]
then echo "$file_name" exists
else
  pax -w -f "$file_name" "$file_dir_name"
  ## alternatively, with tar:
  # tar cf "$file_name" "$file_dir_name"
fi
```

At this point, I'd like to point out the variable name `$file_name` is a bit too generic, it can be changed to something like `$tarball`.

As a bonus, you may consider shortenning your variable names:

1. `$wd` is a good name for your expected working directory, it collides with neither `cd` nor `pwd`
2. I often use just `$f` for files or just any "directory entry"; likewise, `$d` for directory operands.